# an issue when using $state.go method on ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I use $state.go for navigation between views. Before navigation, I control internet connectio like below:

```
if('window.isOnline()){
        $cordovaToast.showLongCenter("No internet connection");
        retun;
     }
   $state.go("xxx");
```

I also used  var **$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction** method  in my app. My problem is that, when I route using $state.go to a view, registerBackButtonAction method does not work. I can not find what the problem or wrong thing is.
Can someone help about this?
Thank in advance.

Comment: There is no `$state.go()` in your code

Comment: sorry, I edit the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It would be great if you could make a fiddle of your problem.